# How can I subtract ranges in one sheet and place the values into another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I was tasked with creating some charts for a coworker. He would like to be able to click a button and see a few things happen, one of which involves the following:

On sheet "2020 Master RMA's", I have columns A and O which have dates in them (in the form m/dd/yyyy). I would like to subtract the two dates from this sheet, and put the results in another sheet called "March Presentation". 
If the value is >30, I would like all of the values to be added up and placed in cell AD56 in "March Presentation". 
If the value is between 30 and 60, I would like all of the values to be added up and placed in cell AE56 in "March Presentation".
If the value is >60, I would like all of the values to be added up and placed in cell AF56 in "March Presentation".

I'm running into some mental roadblocks with how to proceed. One error I keep running into a type-mismatch error with my code:

```
Sub Compile_Click()
  Dim OminusA As Date
  Dim row As Long
  Dim column As Long
  Dim OminusAValue As Integer
  Dim lastRow As Long   
  Sheets("2020 Master RMA's").Select
  lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

  For row = 2 To lastRow
  Worksheets("March Presentation").Range("AD56:AF56").Value = DateDiff("d", Worksheets("2020 Master 
  RMA's").Range("A2" & row).Value, Worksheets("2020 Master RMA's").Range("O2" & row).Value)
  OminusAValue = Int(CDbl(OminusA))

    If OminusAValue < 30 Then
        Worksheets("March Presentation").Range("AD56").Value = OminusAValue
    ElseIf OminusAValue > 30 And Int(CDbl(OminusA)) < 60 Then
        Worksheets("March Presentation").Range("AE56").Value = OminusAValue
    Else
        Worksheets("March Presentation").Range("AF56").Value = OminusAValue
    End If
  Next row
End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: `.Range("A2" & row)` and `.Range("O2" & row)` should probably be `.Range("A" & row)` and `Range("O" & row)`.

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: Dang, I had modified the code a bit since posting...lemme try and think.

Comment: I believe it was the  OminusAValue = Int(CDbl(OminusA)) line

Comment: Sorry, it's the line right above that:

 Worksheets("March Presentation").Range("AD56:AF56").Value = DateDiff("d", Worksheets("2020 Master 
  RMA's").Range("A2" & row).Value, Worksheets("2020 Master RMA's").Range("O2" & row).Value)

Comment: Remove the `2`s as I mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: Okay did that...still getting the same type-mismatch error on the same line :/

Comment: That means one or both of the the cells in columns A and O is not a Date.

Comment: Ah, so there are a few cells in column O that are blank. I went ahead and made the entire A and O column a Date, but still no luck.

I then went and added a IF statement saying that if any cell in A or O was not blank, then to execute the code, but still no luck.

Comment: Maybe use `IsDate` to check if both cells are dates then.

Comment: Yep that was it, thank you!